# How does this work in C++? exposing private virtual member of a derived class through base class

Tags: c++

I found a similar code snippet. Let's assume that there is a good reason to hide the virtual function in the derived class B. But this private member can be exposed via the base class as follows:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << "hello A" << std::endl;}
};

class B: public A {
private:
    void print() const override { std::cout << "hello B" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    const A &a = B();
    a.print();  // works unexpectedly (prints "hello B")
    const B &b = B();
    b.print(); // does not work (as expected)
}
```

Any idea why `a.print()` works, even though A should be dynamically bound to class B at runtime? Or does C++ ignore private/public classifier at runtime?

I executed the code above, didn't expect `a.print()` to work since `print()` is private in the derived class.

Comment: why would `a.print(); ` not work? `print` is public in `A` and you are calling the method through reference to `A`

Comment: When you say "does not work as expected", what *do* you expect? And what actually happens? Please [edit] your question to give use more details.

Comment: this is the expected behavior.  `print` is public in the base class so accessing it through the base class is no issue.  The access control is not transitive.

Comment: "does not work (as expected)" = actually confirms my expectation that it shouldn't work. Thanks anyway, I think @Caleth's explanation makes sense.

Comment: "Or does C++ ignore private/public classifier at runtime?" These are compile-time specifiers for access. Once the code is built, classes as such doesn't really exists any more, only their implementation (functions) and memory areas for the objects.

Comment: Side note: Consider access levels a simple way to prevent many families of bugs. They are not a bullet proof defence, and they're actually quite easy to work around when you want to. They're good at stopping accidents, but not so good with deliberate evasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access control checks is by name, in the context of the static type of the expression it is used in. `A::print` is public, so `a.print()` is valid.

Virtual dispatch is unrelated to access control, so as `a` is bound to a `B` it calls `B::print`. If virtual dispatch considered access control, you would have to defer it to runtime to check, at least in some cases. E.g.

```
extern bool coinflip();
const A &a = coinflip() ? A{} : B{};
a.print();
```

Answer (score 6):

Nothing is being ignored here.

> ```
> const A &a = B();
> a.print();
> ```

In a nutshell: You are calling `print` on a reference to `A`. `print` is `public` in `A`. Only now dynamic dispatch gets its turn. The method is `virtual`, the dynamic type of the object is `B`, so we call `B::print`.

---

Consider that if this would work as you expect, the access would depend on the dynamic type of an object, and in code like this

```
 void foo(const A& a) {
        a.print();
 }
```

It would be impossible to decide if `a.print()` can be called or not. But thats not how it works. To decide if `a.print()` can be accessed we only need to look at `A`.

Answer (score 1):

What is unexpected with this?

```
const A &a = B();
a.print();
```

Let's see what is happening step by step.
When you call assignment operator `=`, you can assume stuff on the right operator is happening first, so you create unnamed temporary object of `class B` (**Important: That object exist in memory from now to the end of scope since you are creating reference to that object** ). With left side of assignment operator you are saying that const reference `a` is now referring to that object. Your reference `a` is type of `class A`, and C++ is allowing that conversion (casting): **Derived class** to **Base class**. But, that casting is not changing memory where unnamed object of `class B` is stored. So when you access `print()` member function with your `a` reference you are actually calling `B.print()`.

The only thing you are accomplishing with reference being type of `class A` is that since `print()` method is public within `class A` you can call it outside the class, as someone already said in comments.

Comment: there is no assignment operator in this code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai What is `=` then?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, my big wrong (kept using term **assignment** for both cases: `int a=5` and `a=5` ), thank you. But the logic of my answer stays the same.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai On the other hand. I refer to **assignment operator**, not **assignment process (statement)**. This is **Initialization process (statement)** but you are using **assignment operator** to accomplish it. There are no term **initialization operator**, and  `=` is certainly an operator, so how would you call it?

Comment: `=` is the equals sign, its not the assignment operator here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Okay, thank you.